# c# listview item is not activating

Tags: c#, listview

I have a ListView and I want to open a new window on click on item of that ListView, but listView1_ItemActivate does nothing.

Example of ItemActivate:

```
    private void listView1_ItemActivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Determine which item was clicked/activated.
        MessageBox.Show("You clicked " + listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text);



    }
```

Why it does not working properly?

Comment: Do you receive an exception or does the `listView1_ItemActivate` just not get called?

Comment: Probably it is just not get called

Comment: Do you register the event handler somewhere? `listView1.ItemActivate += new System.EventHandler(this.listView1_ItemActivate);` Most likely in your designer file.

Comment: I moved this to designer file, but it shows error that listview is a feild, but it is used like a type - what am I missing in designer file?

Comment: You need to put it into the `InitializeComponent` method. After the initialisation of the `listView1`.

Comment: See my two form project : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net

Comment: @jdweng wrong link? this is win forms not asp.net

Comment: My response is using : System.Windows.Forms;

Comment: Ok, it works. But now I want to display data in one form from list view in another form, but every value of instance of class Zadost is null or with value 0.  First form: http://pastebin.com/LCcrpdkc Second form: http://pastebin.com/jvnCQQDa